# product bought by how many unique users?

Tags: python, dataset

i have a dataset like this

```
users                                     b           c       d      product
8fa683e59c02c04cb781ac689686db07    ggstart 1.46276E+12 00:00.0 55107008    
335644267c1d5f04eaea7bc6f51b1861    ggstart 1.46276E+12 00:00.0 55107008    
ca3071aad676bc963795a2b09635cdf0    ggstop  1.46277E+12 00:00.0 55107008    
17412dec7d3d02c9b0b1c3d1c3571c5c    ggstop  1.46276E+12 00:00.0 10655437    
f81167c854f1a0c86cab6188f9995824    ggstart 1.46276E+12 00:00.1 55107008    
17412dec7d3d02c9b0b1c3d1c3571c5c    ggstart 1.46276E+12 00:00.1 10655437    
a2659df45c8d05f326225fa5b1063ac9    ggstart 1.46276E+12 00:00.1 30900473    
b8bbef76f8dfee2fe190a283cd5a19a7    ggstart 1.46276E+12 00:00.1 18121481    
e8ebfc3f39512eda3aa0702b13ffed63    ggstart 1.46276E+12 00:00.1 18121481    
988e4873861347113519fbee6dd1c3b0    ggstart 1.46276E+12 00:00.2 55107008    
583361d66ad8b0827cd08d3a5d64af89    ggstop  1.46276E+12 00:00.2 55107008
```

users, b,c,product are columns.

i have to determine  each product is bought by how many unique users. there are thousands of lines like this.
Keep in mind:

```
there can be many users buying the same product,
each customer have more than one product bought
```

first i tried to make matrix of unique users and unique PRODUCT. BUT i have only 16 product and users are like 5000.
is there any approach i can find

Answer (score 0):

Use [`groupby/nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html):

```
In [51]: df.groupby(['product'])['users'].nunique()
Out[51]: 
product
10655437    1
18121481    2
30900473    1
55107008    6
Name: users, dtype: int64
```

Comment: thanks unutbu, can u explain me, how it worked. and i was trying making matrix  and then accessing the values

Comment: Start by reading the [Groupby: split-apply-combine tutorial](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#group-by-split-apply-combine). It doesn't mention `nunique` explicitly, but if you use [IPython](https://ipython.org/), then its tab-completion feature will help you find out that the `SeriesGroupBy` object has a `nunique` method.